# Are inner page table stored on the disk when not needed?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging

My understanding regarding multi-level paging is: There is always at least one page table in memory, so that it is able to reference to the other page tables. The other, "inner" page tables are not always in memory, only when needed so that there isn't a gigantic page table always in memory.

So is it correct that these other page tables are stored on the SSD for example and only loaded in memory when needed?

Answer (score 0):

In theory; it is possible for an OS to support sending page tables to swap space.

In practice; most (possibly all) operating systems don't support sending page tables to swap space. I'd assume it's considered too much hassle for too little benefit; partly because the size of a page table is small relative to the amount of virtual memory that depends on its presence.

Comment: But what is the advantage of multi-layer swapping then? If all inner paging tables are in memory anyway, how does it save memory space?

Comment: @Dash11235: Most page tables aren't used, don't exist and cost nothing. For example; if a process uses 123 MiB of virtual space then it might have 63 inner page tables (out of maybe a maximum of 512 of them, so 449 of them don't exist and cost nothing) and one outer page table. The advantage to sending an inner page table to swap would be that for every larger (maybe 2 MiB) area of virtual address space sent to swap space you can also send its corresponding tiny (maybe 4 KiB) inner page table to swap space; so you can save slightly more RAM (maybe 0.19% more, or `4 KiB / 2 MiB` more).

Comment: But why would you split it then into inner page tables? Can't you just use one big flat page table and simply check which part of the virtual memory is not used and simply not map it?

Comment: @Dash11235: For 2 levels (or more levels) of page tables you get "most page tables aren't used, don't exist and cost nothing". For a single flat table you can't do that (all of a huge table's entries must exist regardless of whether they're used or not) so you waste a huge amount of RAM for literally nothing. E.g. for modern 80x86 (48-bit virtual addresses, 4 KiB pages, 8 byte page table entries) a single huge table would cost `8 * (1 << (48 - 12) ) = 1 << 39 = 512 GiB` of RAM (per process).

Comment: I just don't understand why a flat page table must have all entries. Wouldn't it be possible to put only the pages that are used into the page table?

Comment: @Dash11235: Think of a single flat page table like an array of pointers (where array entries can be set to NULL) - you could have a table with an adjustable size or limit, but if you have one thing at the start (e.g. a program's code) and one thing at the end (e.g. the kernel) you have to have a massive unused waste of space in the middle.

Comment: Yea, I wans't able to grasp the concept of pretty much summarizing multiple empty pages  (The huge unused virtual address space between heap and stack) into one empty page in the page directory. I get it now, appreciate the patience and help.